# Nautilus won't open

Tags: nautilus, places

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. I can't get Nautilus to open anything from the Places menu or a folder on my desktop.

What I can do for a folder on my desktop is right click, open with other application.  I have 2 choices, Files or File Browser.  If I choose Files it opens immediately.  However, if I choose File Browser nothing happens.

How do I edit the entry so that everything opens using Files?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  The command was `nautilus --no-desktop --browser %U`.
When I ran this is terminal I received this error:

> Could not parse arguments: Unknown option --browser

Once I removed that from the command and --no-desktop it works fine.  Only remaining issue (if you want to call it that), is that when I right click and Open With, I have to use Files instead of File Browser.  Or I could just double click.